# Value Error: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv1d_9

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, cnn, lstm

i am trying to implement classification model on my dataset, which has 3 columns and 651 rows
Displacement Time Labels
0.000245879 0.01 Undamage
0.001954869 0.02 Damage
0.006545664 0.03 Undamage
0.015357094 0.04 Undamage
0.029615621 0.05 Damage
In output it produce accuracy of 99% and during confusion matrix it only classify 125 lables as damaged and un damaged
can you guide me what is wrong with this code
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, LSTM, Dense, Flatten
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

Load your dataset
data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/LabeledSignal.xls')

Extract features and labels
features = data[['Displacement', 'Time']].values
labels = data['Labels'].values

Encode labels to numerical values
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)

Define constants
sequence_length = 1 # Each data point is treated as a separate sequence
num_features = 2 # Number of features (Displacement and Time)

Reshape the features for input to CNN-LSTM
X = features.reshape(features.shape[0], sequence_length, num_features)

Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

Define and compile the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, num_features), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')) # Output layer for binary classification

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=35, validation_split=0.1)

Evaluate the model on the test set and obtain class predictions
y_prob = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_prob, axis=1)

Calculate the confusion matrix
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

Display the confusion matrix
print("Confusion Matrix:")
print(confusion)

Plot the confusion matrix
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(confusion, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', xticklabels=['Damaged', 'Undamaged'], yticklabels=['Damaged', 'Undamaged'])
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Actual')
plt.show()

Generate classification report
report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=['Damaged', 'Undamaged'])
print("Classification Report:")
print(report)

Evaluate the model on the test set
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Loss: {loss:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {accuracy*100:.2f}%")

and when i try to pass pool size morte then 1 then it generate this error
ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv1d_9. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 1, 2] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.